# What is the difference between an XML attribute and an XML token?

Tags: xml, xpath, indexing, basex

I have been reading through [BaseX's documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Indexes) and I found they offer a token index as well as an attribute token. However, it is not clear to me what the difference between the two is.

Attributes seem to be the regular attributes as I know them:

```
<node attribute="value"/>
```

However, for tokens the documentation reads:

> In many XML dialects, such as HTML or DITA, multiple tokens are stored
>   in attribute values.

So it would almost seem as if tokens are values for attributes? So, like this:

```
<node attribute="token1 token2"/>
```

If that is the case, what is indexed in both these cases then? If the attribute index improves equality checks such as

```
//country[@car_code = 'J']
```

and a token index improves containment checks such as

```
//div[contains-token(@class, 'row')]
```

isn't a token index then simply an advanced attribute index, working with multiple values? Or am I missing something? When would one use the one or the other, and are they ever useful in combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately *token* means a few different things in different contexts in XPath, XML, XML Schema, DTDs, and other related technologies which can make it a bit unclear when the term comes up.

Here they are referring to *token* in the sense of a string made up of XML name chars.

Of the many ways that attributes can be defined, one case is as having multiple tokens separated by whitespace, with no meaning assigned to the order of such tokens. To take one of the examples you quote:

```
//div[contains-token(@class, 'row')]
```

This would match each of:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="row important">
<div class="important row">
<div class="important        row               warning">
```

It would not match any of:

```
<div class="rows">
<div class="arrow">
```

> isn't a token index then simply an advanced attribute index, working with multiple values?

Yes. A very useful one. Writing a test for an attribute containing a value as a token so that it would match each of the four cases it should match above, but none of the two cases it shouldn't match would be very fiddly, and in a lot of cases this need comes up a lot (the example above matches the CSS selector `div.row` for example).

Also, note that while a very common use-case for this function is with attribute values, it operates on any string, so it could also be element text, the result of another string function, an entire imported document, etc.

> When would one use the one or the other

Really it's a matter of what you care about. Is your query "I want to match all `<div>`s that have a `class` attribute of `"row"`" or is your query "I want to match all `<div>`s that have a `class` attribute that contains the token `"row"`. In HTML or XHTML considering how `class` is used, we'd probably be in the latter case most of the time.

> and are they ever useful in combination?

In a way, they already are in combination; you are using the `[]` and `@` to identify nodes that have a particular attribute, and then using the `contains-token` function to specify what you do in filtering the values of those attributes.

We generally wouldn't care to do both a `=` test and a `contains-token` test on the same attribute as generally the `=` should suffice; if we've a requirement of what the entire contents of the attribute must be then any requirement of what tokens are present is entailed by that. Of course all sorts of surprising rare cases can happen in coding, especially when we are bringing two or more separate criteria together. It's also more common to have both types working on separate attributes;

```
//a[@href = 'http://example.net/][contains-token(@class, 'cool')]
```

Would use `=` on one attribute and `contains-token` on another.

(Again, really `contains-token` isn't a type of index, its a string function that works on strings, that is often useful within indices).

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. So an attribute index would index your second example on the whole string `row important`, whereas a token would use `row` and `important` separately?  Could you perhaps elaborate on my lost question, namely if the two indexes should be used together, and why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

The term "name token" originates from SGML attributes declared in a DTD like this

```
<!ATTLIST your-element an-attribute-name NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>
```

or an enumerated attribute value declaration like this

```
<!ATTLIST your-element an-attribute-name (value1|value2) #IMPLIED>
```

(or similarly with the attribute types `ID`, `IDREF`, `NAME`, `NAMES`, `NMTOKENS` etc., where a `NMTOKEN` attribute can begin with a digit, but `NAME` must not).

In an XML instance, a name token or enumerated attribute can be used as follows

```
<your-element an-attribute="whatever">
```

(for the first example), or

```
<your-element an-attribute="value1">
```

(for the second).

In SGML, enumerated attributes can be written in a short form syntax like this

```
<your-element value1>
```

eg. the attribute *name* can be omitted, provided that `value1` is unique among all name tokens in the DTD.

HTML has so-called *Boolean Attributes* which are basically SGML enumerated attributes with the additional proviso that the attribute value must be identical to the attribute name. Examples:

```
<div hidden>
<option selected>
```

etc. HTML has the additional quirk that it may expose `true`/`false` as DOM attribute values.

That said, the documentation you linked says that

> The XQuery functions `fn:contains-token`, `fn:tokenize` and `fn:idref` are rewritten for index access whenever possible.